# Linear transformation in matrix space

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Say that $T:S\to S$ is defined by
$$T(A)=\frac{(MA+AM)}2$$
where $A\in S$, and S is defined by
$$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&c\end{bmatrix}: a,b,c\in\mathbb R\right\}$$
and
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Show that T is a linear transformation and build its matrix representation according to the following basis of S:
$$\beta_S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
I think I've been able to prove that $T$ is a linear transformation, since $T(B)+T(C)=T(B+C)$ and $cT(B)=T(cB)$, but I'm really lost about how to find the matrix representation for $T$, I haven't been able to find an exercise quite like this in SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For convenience, denote the elements of our basis by $\beta_S = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.  We find that
$$
T(v_1) = \frac 12 \left( \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0} + \pmatrix{0&-1\\0&0}\right) = 
\pmatrix{0&-1/2\\1/2&0}
\\ = (0)v_1 + (-1/2)v_2 + (0)v_3
$$
It follows that the first column of our matrix $[T]_{\beta_S}$ is given by $(0,-1/2,0)$.  Repeat this for the remaining two columns.  You should find
$$
[T]_{\beta_S} = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\-1/2&0&-1/2\\0&1&0}
$$

---

An example in which we use the matrix: we find
$$
T \pmatrix{1&2\\-2&3} = 
T (v_1 + 2v_2 + 3v_3) = 
T \pmatrix{1\\2\\3}_{\beta_S} =
[T]_{\beta_S} \pmatrix{1\\2\\3}_{\beta_S} =\\ 
\left[\pmatrix{0&1&0\\-1/2&0&-1/2\\0&1&0} \pmatrix{1\\2\\3} \right]_{\beta_{S}}
= \pmatrix{2\\-2\\2}_{\beta_S} = \\
2v_1 - 2v_2 + 2v_3 = \pmatrix{2&-2\\2&2}
$$

Comment: I did find that answer, but it's still not very clear in my head what it means. Now that I have $T$, how would I approach finding $T(X)$, $X$ being some matrix of $S$? The fact that $S$ is a set of $2\times2$ matrices and T is $3\times3$ confuses me especially (even though I understand that $dim(S) = 3$).

Comment: @AstlyDichrar Actually you're not multiplying the matrix $A$ with $[T]_{\beta_S}$. In fact you're multiplying the coefficient matrix of $A$ wrt to the given basis.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: That is much clearer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can sleep peacefully tonight.